# How do I create a workflow that actually works in Visio?

Tags: workflow

I have created a test workflow in Visio and ran the check document query and it returns it as OK. I export to Sharepoint designer and try an run the query and get an error. Does the query all have to be logical for it to work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The actions have to be pretty simple from Visio.  Once a workflow is imported from Visio to spd, it can't be moved back.

In a boot camp I was told the idea behind starting with a visio workflow is to give a business high level design first.  Plus you can see the Visio workflow on sp as it executes.

Answer (score 0):

Visio does not configure the actions. it only lays out the logic path. Once you import into SPD you need to configure the actions to make the workflow functional. You can export back to Visio, but you will lose any configurations you have added in SPD.